# Sending byte[] to Java REST POST changes actual array

Tags: java, spring, rest, arrays

I  have a Spring REST service set up which has a POST method to receive a byte array. The goal of this method is to accept a zipped JSON string, hence the byte array. The unzipped string is to be mapped to a list and then sent to a database.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/receiveData.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public
@ResponseBody boolean receiveData(@RequestParam byte[] data, 
                                  @RequestParam String configurationName) {
    String jsonString = ZipController.unZip(data);
    JSONMapper jsonMapper = new JSONMapper();
    List<Message> messages = null;
    try {
        messages = jsonMapper.parseToMessage(jsonString, configurationName);
        saveData(messages);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The zipping and the unzipping of the String works without flaws, as tests that I have written show. The converting to a list and then storing it in a database works perfectly too. However, when I zip a string, and send it to the address, somehow it isn't recognized as a zip anymore. Further digging revealed that the actual byte[] has completely changed in the process. Before I send it, the array prints to

```
[B@7186333e
```

However, after sending it, it suddenly prints to (for example)

```
[B@fee07cc
```

This appears to be random, but the [B@ is always the same. The rest is random. I am using the REST-assured framework to test, but SOAPui gives the same problem. The code I'm using to send the call is:

```
expect().
body(containsString("true")).
when().
given().
parameters("data",ZipController.zip(correctJSONMessage)).
post("/receiveData.do");
```

The method returns a true or false as feedback whether it succeded or not.

The whole service runs on a Tomcat 6 server, is it possible that this messes with the array? How can I fix this?

Comment: What you actually want to know is "how can I print the contents of an array?"?

Comment: FYI --  the `[b@XXXXXX` notation is showing you the Java type (an array of bytes) along with the memory location of the object (in hex after the @).

Comment: (`[B@7186333e` is *not* the contents of the array)

Comment: Check that there is an encoding, whenever `String/byte[]` conversions are done: `string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` and `new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`. And the zip stream should either call `close()` or `finish()` at the end. Furthermore `GZípOutputStream` (gzip) seems more appropriate then zip.